# ALSA 'snd_pcm_writei' behavior in blocking mode

Tags: c, linux, alsa, audio-player

I slightly modified the demo taken from [ALSA Project website](https://alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2pcm_min_8c-example.html) in order to test it on my laptop's sound card (Intel PCH ALC3227 Analog, Ubuntu 18.04), which requires 2 channels and 16 bit integers. I also doubled the latency (1 s), switched off resampling and made the demo lasts longer. This is the code (runtime error checking not pasted for sake of synthesis)

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char *device = "hw:1,0"; /* playback device */
snd_output_t *output = NULL;
unsigned char buffer[16*1024]; /* some random data */
int main(void) {
    int err;
    unsigned int i;
    snd_pcm_t *handle;
    snd_pcm_sframes_t frames;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++)
        buffer[i] = (unsigned char) (rand() & 0xff);
    snd_pcm_open(&handle, device, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0)
    snd_pcm_set_params(handle, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE,
            SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED, 2, 48000, 0, 1E6);
    // Print actual buffer size
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hw_params;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc(&hw_params);
    snd_pcm_hw_params_current(handle, hw_params);
    snd_pcm_uframes_t bufferSize;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size(hw_params, &bufferSize);
    printf("ALSA buffer size = %li\n", bufferSize);
    // playback
    for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        frames = snd_pcm_writei(handle, buffer, sizeof(buffer) / 4);
        if (frames < 0)
            frames = snd_pcm_recover(handle, (int) frames, 0);
        if (frames < 0) {
            printf("snd_pcm_writei failed: %s\n", snd_strerror((int) frames));
            break;
        }
        if (frames > 0 && frames < (long) sizeof(buffer) / 4)
            printf("Short write (expected %li, wrote %li)\n",
                    (long) sizeof(buffer) / 4, frames);
    }
    snd_pcm_hw_params_free(hw_params);
    snd_pcm_close(handle);
    return (0);
}
```

Audio works but could someone explain me why I sometimes get output like the following

```
ALSA buffer size = 16384
Short write (expected 4096, wrote 9)
Short write (expected 4096, wrote 4080)
```

indicating that less frames than expected have been written by `snd_pcm_writei`? According to the [ALSA docs](https://alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#gabc748a500743713eafa960c7d104ca6f), I understand that a signal has to be occurred, but I don't get the reason and which signal is.

I also tried to halve the `buffer`'s size, but the result is pretty the same.

Answer (score 2):

A short read is reported when an error happens, but some frames were already written successfully.

You are supposed to call the same function again, with the remaining buffer; if the error was not transient, it will be reported then.
(This example code is wrong; it just ignores that the remaining part of the buffer was not written.)

Comment: If there was an error, the function should have returned the error code, should not it? For instance, -EPIPE for underrun.

Comment: Then the information about the number of written frames would have been lost. This behaviour for write() is specified by POSIX.